# Unnecessary white space in ifesle R programming

Tags: r, if-statement

While trying out ifelse in R programming, when the words I tried to print, as result for each elements of vectors, have different length there is an un wanted extra white space. How should I resolve it? "trimws()" is not working[![tried out this, Here "fail & Average"] are words of different length hence fail is having extra space[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EloGu.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EloGu.png)

Comment: Use `cat()`? E.g. `v <- c(20, 30, 60, 35, 70); cat(ifelse(v>50, "Average", "fail"))`

Comment: No problem - please in future add more details to your question to help us help you (see e.g. [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/12957340))

Comment: @jared_mamrot You should post that comment as an answer to the dupe.

Comment: Good idea @RuiBarradas - I will - thanks :)